# Archivos activity_main.xml y content_main.xml

Tags: android-studio

Leí la respuesta que dieron a: *"¿Cuál es la diferencia entre `content_main xml` y `activity_main xml` en `Android studio`?"* de hace 6 meses atrás.

Me despejo la duda. Pero me surge otra: **¿En cuál de los dos debo colocar los objetos** (`TextView`, `Button`, etc.) **de la parte diseño?** Porque ambos archivos `.xml` tienen una parte diseño (Design).

Tengo instalado `Android Studio 2.2.3`.
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 1):

> "¿Cuál es la diferencia entre content_main xml y activity_main xml en
>   Android studio?"

La diferencia en realidad es simplemente el nombre, y que content_main.xml, generalmente se usa para cargar mediante un include otros elementos, mediante :

```
include layout="@layout/content_main
```

Pero simplemente es una nomenclatura la cual no es una restricción.

**Ambos archivos pueden contener los elementos que deseas se muestren en tu UI y pueden llamarse como tu desees.**(manteniendo la restricción para nomenclatura de recursos), incluso puedes crear tu propio layout.

Por ejemplo `layout_principal.xml`, agregar elementos y cargarlo mediante `setContentView()` a tu `Activity` y crear otro layout que contenga elementos de la UI llamado `contenido_principal.xml`, el cual seria cargado mediante `<include>`.

---

> ¿En cuál de los dos debo colocar los objetos (TextView, Button, etc.)
>   de la parte diseño? Porque ambos archivos .xml tienen una parte diseño
>   (Design)

Puedes colocarloa directamente dentro del layout que carga tu Activity mediante `setContentView()` o si deseas puedes agregarlos en otro layout que seria por ejemplo `content_main.xml`, y cargar este layout desde el layout principal mediante :

```
include layout="@layout/content_main
```

Te recomiendo leer:

[Reusando layouts con `<include>`](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)